# toLocaleString returning strange characters sometimes

Tags: javascript

Occasionally I am having a field populated with strange characters:

ý9ý:ý28ý ýAM

Here is the code:

```
var options = {
          hour: 'numeric',
          minute: 'numeric',
          hour12: true
        };

        var timeString = entryTime.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Have you logged `entryTime`

Comment: Perhaps `entryTime` is a string? `"ý9ý:ý28ý ýAM".toLocaleString("en-US", {hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true})` is `"ý9ý:ý28ý ýAM"`.

Comment: This question lacks a MCVE. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not actually able to reproduce it yet, so I have not logged it.

Comment: @Bidwell So then it's not a problem?